# Android manifest file: always start application from the beaning when user resuming the application after pressing the home button

Tags: android

My application contain some default intent and user defined ,i want my application to start always from the beaning when user resuming the application after pressing the home button

Comment: what you are telling is not the "android way". home button is not meant to kill the app.

Comment: @Varun i know it's not the android way ,but i need to do some stuff when user press the home button.am trying to find out a method that's unique to home button but i can't get it, so now am looking for some settings mainfest file so that when user resume the app after pressing home button the app need to restart from begning.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever the 'Home' button is pressed, the application is paused. and onPause() is called.

Whenever it is resumes, onResume() method is called.

override the onResume() method, as you override onCreate(), and do all the things necessary to be done when application resumes, inside the onResume() method.

Comment: Thats quite expressive buddy. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Sudeep , Supporting Sheikh Alam I would like to add  below code to your activity to track whether your activity is focussed

```
  @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged (hasFocus);      
        if(hasFocus){
            //your code here when app has focus
        }       
    }
```

Hope it helps!Good Luck!

Comment: i think when am resuming my app hasfocus is true, and this condition is true at all the time my app running and am returning from my default intent and resuming my app, also falls when am performing default and press home button:     Thanks for your information, This is the problem in case of OnResume , that execute when am return to my app in both case retrun from home button or return from default intent